# R: "[" function behaves differently than the same named "foo"

Tags: r, data.table

Could you explain me why naming the function "[" changes it's behavior like in the example below..?

```
library(data.table)

d <- data.table(data.frame(a=1:10))
class(d) <- c(class(d), "bar")

foo <- function(data, x) {
  data[, .(.N), keyby=eval(substitute(x), envir=data)]
}

"[.bar" <- function(data, x) {
  data[, .(.N), keyby=eval(substitute(x), envir=data)]
}
```

Results:

```
   > d[a < 5]
   a
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
> foo(d, a < 5)
   substitute N
1:      FALSE 6
2:       TRUE 4
```

And:

```
> foo(d, a)
    substitute N
 1:          1 1
 2:          2 1
 3:          3 1
 4:          4 1
 5:          5 1
 6:          6 1
 7:          7 1
 8:          8 1
 9:          9 1
10:         10 1
> d[a]
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'a' not found
```

They should work the same, aren't they?

Thanks!

Comment: your question is not clear. what is the expected output, and error? also, what is `f(d, a)`, since you haven't defined `f`?

Comment: @Tim Regarding the error, try `d[(a)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two give the same output.

```
> foo(d, a<5 )
   substitute V1
1:      FALSE  6
2:       TRUE  4

> "[.bar"(d,a<5)
   substitute V1
1:      FALSE  6
2:       TRUE  4
```

Please specify which behavior change are you talking about.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the problem thanks to the person who already deleted his/her response:

```
class(d) <- c("bar")

foo <- function(data, x) {
  data <- unclass(data)
  data <- as.data.table(data)
  data[, .(.N), keyby=eval(substitute(x), envir=data)]
}

"[.bar" <- function(data, x) {
  data <- unclass(data)
  data <- as.data.table(data)
  data[, .(.N), keyby=eval(substitute(x), envir=data)]
}
```

As you see, it was a problem of class given.